# Is it possible to wait for unknown Tasks to complete?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Using the .NET Task Parallel Library, is there an in-built way to wait for all running Tasks to complete, without actually having a reference to the Tasks?

`Task.WaitAny()` and `Task.WaitAll()` both require an array of `Task` instances. What I'd like is something like `Task.WaitAll()` which takes no arguments, and just waits for any and all Tasks spawned by my application to complete.

If not, I'll build something into my framework, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I can help it.

Comment: By 'all running tasks' do you mean Tasks that you created in your process/application?

Comment: @n8wrl: I said "any and all Tasks spawned by my application"... so yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since any `Task` could be spawned by any .NET code (i.e. BCL, some library, etc.) you probably don't want to wait on all tasks that are outstanding, but just the ones that your own code has created. The simplest way is to create your own factory that uses the underlying one that tracks all unfinished tasks and exposes the desired wait functions

```
public class MyTaskFactory {
    private HashSet<Task> _tasks = new HashSet<Task>();

    public Task<T> StartNew<T>(Func<T> func) {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(func);
        t.ContinueWith(x => {
          lock(_tasks) {
            _tasks.Remove(x);
          }
        });
        lock(_tasks) {
          _tasks.Add(t);
        }
        return t;
    }

    // ... implement other StartNew overrides ...

    public void WaitAll() {
        Task[] tasks;
        lock(_tasks) {
          tasks = _tasks.ToArray();
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done something quite similar to this, but I'm allowing my classes to maintain their own list of tasks and implement the same WaitAll() method you've written, which is exposed by an IUsesTasks interface. This fits in well with my current framework. However, I like your idea too, perhaps more than mine. +1.

Comment: I'm accepting this as I ended up doing something similar, and I love the `t.ContinueWith(x => _tasks.Remove(x));`, which I hadn't thought of. Thanks.

Comment: This code is not thread safe. For example,  if `StartNew` is invoked by parallel tasks, calls to `Remove` or `Add` may be attempted in parallel on the container that is not thread safe. Also, if a task finishes during the call to `WaitAll`, `Remove` may be called concurrently to `ToArray`. These problems can be solved by locking, or using a thread-safe collection instead of the `HashSet`, but there are more subtle problems as well: for example, if one of the tasks you are currently waiting on calls `StartNew`, you gonna have a "leaked" task.

Comment: @Branko Duh.. That's what i get for posting a toy implementation. Fixed the concurrency issues. The second one you mention is a bit more complex. If i lock _tasks for the waitall, it could lead to deadlock. I run a loop waiting on all and remove completed tasks until tasks is depleted. I'll leave that implementation to the reader :)

Answer (score 5):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but you could change your architecture so all the tasks are created as children of one "main" task. Waiting on this "main" task will then automatically wait on all its children.

You can create a child task like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => /* ... */,
    TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
);
```

You may find the following links useful when it comes to the topic of child tasks:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx (see the "Task Chaining with Parent/Child Tasks" section)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx

Comment: That's a neat idea - I'll consider it. Thanks. +1